# Crystal report is not showing data using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am using Asp.net 4.0 and Sap crystal report my problem is that I am unable to show data on to the reportViewer after binding the dataset.

Below is my Aspx designer code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="productRepot.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProductionPlanning1.productRepot" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:Label ID="prdt_Label1" runat="server" Text="ProductID"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="matrl_TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="rpt_Button1" runat="server" Text="PrintProduct" 
    onclick="rpt_Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="product_CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    AutoDataBind="true"></CR:CrystalReportViewer>

</asp:Content>
```

Product Report.aspx.cs

```
  protected void rpt_Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DataSet2 DS2 = new DataSet2();
        //Fyp_1.Product pp = new Fyp_1.Product();
        //DS2.Tables.Add(pp.GetProduct(Convert.ToInt16(matrl_TextBox.Text)).Copy());
        //DS2.Tables[0].TableName = "Product";
        //CrystalReportProduct TR = new CrystalReportProduct();
        //TR.SetDataSource(DS2);
        //product_CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = TR;
        //product_CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

        GenerateReport();




        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //BookTicket_Class BT = new BookTicket_Class();
           //ds.Tables.Add(BT.GetBookTicketReport(Convert.ToInt16(TicketNO_TextBox.Text)).Copy());
        //ds.Tables[0].TableName = "BookTicket";
        //TicketReport TR = new TicketReport();
        //TR.SetDataSource(ds);
        //CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = TR;
        //CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GenerateReport()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PROZECK-   PC\R2MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FYP;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand comd;
        comd = new SqlCommand();
        comd.Connection = sqlConn;
        comd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comd.CommandText = "spgetproductNEW";



        comd.Parameters.Add("@MaterialID", SqlDbType.Int);
      //  int VAL = Convert.ToInt32(matrl_TextBox.Text);
        if (matrl_TextBox.Text.Trim() != "")
            comd.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(matrl_TextBox.Text);
        else
            comd.Parameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;




        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = comd;

        DataSet2 DS2 = new DataSet2();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(DS2, "Product");

        //oRpt.SetDataSource(ds);

        //CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

        //CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;
        CrystalReportProduct TR = new CrystalReportProduct();
        TR.SetDataSource(DS2);
        product_CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = TR;
       // product_CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();




    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the problem is described to you .

[image]

But when I check the data in  crystal report designer it show the data 
[image]

My FIRST code of binding the data was this then i  changed it in to the above code i paste

```
        DataSet2 DS2 = new DataSet2();
        Fyp_1.Product pp = new Fyp_1.Product();
        DS2.Tables.Add(pp.GetProduct(Convert.ToInt16(matrl_TextBox.Text)).Copy());
        DS2.Tables[0].TableName = "Product";
        CrystalReportProduct TR = new CrystalReportProduct();
        TR.SetDataSource(DS2);
        product_CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = TR;
        product_CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing the final call; `product_CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh();`

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the reference crystalReport.web dll and then add latest version of crystalReport.web dll then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

iam also faced same problem finally i got it 
 here is the solution

goto webform1.aspx-->source
 and this

after that goto the following  path
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319
here u see the " crystalreportviewers13 "copy this folder

right click on ur project

we saw the OPEN FILE IN FILEEXPLORER  click on it you can paste ur crystalreportviewers13 here

after that goto FILE and CLOSE
current solution is succesfully closed .
next goto FILE --> RECENT FILES AND PROJECTS  open ur solution from here     ::))

see my comment also

Comment: goto webform1.aspx-->source and this <script type="text/javascript" src="/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"></script>